# Foreach Loop Only Updating One Database Row

Tags: mysql, vb.net, loops, foreach

I'm trying to develop a feature in vb.net to auto-flag an item in mysql database as *expired, less than 7 days, less than a month, less than 2 months, less than 3 months*.

I know the loops I'm using are right based on the text in the labels on the top right. However, it's only updating one of the rows in the database. Here's an [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T2CO.png) of what I'm getting. **So the question is: How do I code so that all rows in the database are updated?**

```
Public Sub insertStatus()
    Dim tDate As Date
    Dim eDate As Date
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim query, query2, updateQ1, updateQ2, updateQ3, updateQ4, updateQ5, updateQ6 As String
    Dim adpt As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim dSet As New DataSet
    Dim dRow As DataRow

    connection = New MySqlConnection
    connection.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=luce;password=root;database=chemicalinventoryrecord;Allow Zero Datetime = True"
    Try
        connection.Open()
        tDate = Date.Today
        query = "select * from chemicalinventory"
        query2 = "select expiryDate from chemicalinventory"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
        command1 = New MySqlCommand(query2, connection)
        adpt.SelectCommand = command
        adpt.Fill(dSet, "chemicalinventory")
        reader = command1.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            For Each dRow In dSet.Tables(0).Rows
                eDate = CType(reader.GetMySqlDateTime("expiryDate"), Date)
                If (eDate - tDate).Days < 7 And (eDate - tDate).Days >= 1 Then
                    lblTest2.Text = "Less than 7 days"
                    updateQ1 = "update chemicalinventoryrecord.chemicalinventory set remark ='" & lblTest2.Text & "'  where DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())<7 and DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())>=1 "
                    command = New MySqlCommand(updateQ1, connection)

                    Exit For
                ElseIf (tDate - eDate).Days >= 0 Then
                    lblTest1.Text = "Expired"
                    updateQ2 = "update chemicalinventoryrecord.chemicalinventory set remark = '" & lblTest1.Text & "' where DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate)>=0"
                    command2 = New MySqlCommand(updateQ2, connection)

                    Exit For
                ElseIf (eDate - tDate).Days < 30 And (eDate - tDate).Days >= 7 Then
                    updateQ3 = "update chemicalinventoryrecord.chemicalinventory set remark = 'Expiring in less than 1 month' where DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())<30 and DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())>=7"
                    command4 = New MySqlCommand(updateQ3, connection)

                    Exit For
                ElseIf (eDate - tDate).Days < 60 And (eDate - tDate).Days >= 30 Then
                    lblTest3.Text = "Less than 2 month"
                    updateQ4 = "update chemicalinventoryrecord.chemicalinventory set remark = '" & lblTest3.Text & "'where DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())<60 and DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())>=30"
                    command5 = New MySqlCommand(updateQ4, connection)

                    Exit For
                ElseIf (eDate - tDate).Days < 90 And (eDate - tDate).Days >= 60 Then
                    updateQ5 = "update chemicalinventoryrecord.chemicalinventory set remark = 'Expiring in less than 3 months' where DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())<90 and DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())>=60"
                    command6 = New MySqlCommand(updateQ5, connection)
                    Exit For
                Else
                    updateQ6 = "update chemicalinventoryrecord.chemicalinventory set remark =' ' where DateDiff(expiryDate, CURDATE())>90"
                    command3 = New MySqlCommand(updateQ6, connection)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End While
        reader.Close()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        connection.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub`
```

Comment: This whole operation seems pointless to me. You don't want a table that contains a `Remark` column whose value goes out of date because it depends on nothing but the `expiryDate` column. Create a view and let the database calculate that value every time you query it. Look at what the `CASE` statement can do.

Comment: It remains a very bad idea to store a transient calculated value.  Tomorrow, every single one of those could be out of date/wrong.  You also do not need 2 (or 6???!) queries to work with one table.  That remark text does not need to be in the database in order to be shown to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used a simple stored procedure to get data from database

Vb side:

```
    Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
    Dim myConnectionString As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    myConnectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;" _
                & "uid=Monica;" _
                & "pwd=12345;" _
                & "database=Monica;"

    Try
        conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
        conn.Open()  '' open connection

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then  '' check connection state 
            cmd.CommandText = "selectDataWithRemark"
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim adap As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            adap.Fill(ds)

        End If

        Try
            If Not ds Is Nothing Then  '' check ds before assigning to datagridview 

                If ds.Tables.Count > 0 Then
                    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                        dgvChemicalTable.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("DataGridView Error : " & ex.Message)
        End Try

        conn.Close() '' close connection 


    Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show("Database Coonection Error : " & ex.Message)
    End Try
```

MySql side:

```
       CREATE PROCEDURE `Monica`.`selectDataWithRemark` ()
       BEGIN


       SELECT Serial as Serial_Number,Name as Chemical_Name, 
              MolecularFormula  as Formula, DateReceived as Received_Date,
              DateExpired as Expiry_Date,
              DATEDIFF(DateExpired, DateReceived)     as Days_left,
              CASE
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(DateExpired, DateReceived) <= 0 THEN 'Expired'
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(DateExpired, DateReceived) < 7 THEN 'Expiring in less Less than 7 days'
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(DateExpired, DateReceived) < 30 THEN 'Expiring in less than 1 month'
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(DateExpired, DateReceived) < 60 THEN 'Expiring in less than 2 months'
                 WHEN DATEDIFF(DateExpired, DateReceived) < 90 THEN 'Expiring in less than 3 months'
                 ELSE 'Plenty of days left'
              END AS Remark

     FROM  test;

    END $$
```

----output -----
[image]

PC @Tomalak used your code but add else condition to handle null exception

Comment: Thank you for responding. I already have a remark field in my database table, So, by `END AS Remark`, will it create a new field for me? Also, do I have to include `END CASE`? What is Monika in ``CREATE PROCEDURE `Monika`.`selectDataWithRemark`()``? I see it's neither the database name nor the uid.

Comment: @lucynda yes it will create new Remark field. 'As field name' used to give alias name to existing column  and also assign name to a result set column. in my case i don't have remark field in database.

Comment: i apologise for the confusion in CREATE PROCEDURE `Monika`.`selectDataWithRemark`() 'Monika' is my test database name please use your own database name. i have edited my answer.

Comment: if your remark field having the value you want to display then just use simple select query to get value else update table and set remark field value i hope i satisfied your questions

Comment: Yes, you have!!! And thank you very much for helping out. My program now works fine and I dare say I learned much from you and @Tomalak.

Comment: @Lucynda I am pleased we made it together :)

Answer (score 0):

Creating a column whose contents is based on no other factor than the value of *another* column is a very bad idea. Don't do that.

What you want is a database query like this:

```sql
SELECT
    col1, col2, etc, expiryDate,
    CASE
        WHEN DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate) < 0 THEN 'Expired'
        WHEN DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate) < 7 THEN 'Expiring in less Less than 7 days'
        WHEN DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate) < 30 THEN 'Expiring in less than 1 month'
        WHEN DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate) < 60 THEN 'Expiring in less than 2 months'
        WHEN DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate) < 90 THEN 'Expiring in less than 3 months'
    END AS remark
FROM
    chemicalinventoryrecord.chemicalinventory
```

You can store it as a database view or you can use it directly in your a application.

This way the `remark` column will always be correct and you won't need any external code that runs every day to keep it up to date.

Starting with MySQL 5.7.5 you could even add the `CASE` expression as a [calculated column](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/) to the original table if you don't want to use a separate view.

Comment: I have tried your codes, but I'm getting this error:
*syntax error near 'case when DateDiff(CURDATE, expiryDate)<0 then 'Expired' when DateDiff(CURDA'.*
I'm developing the application using vb.net, so I declared a variable for the query and entered the query as `query = "select ..."`, how do I get the syntax right?

Comment: The SQL syntax is fine. Compare. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/706bca/1 (I've just copied the code and removed the `DateDiff()` calculation.)

Comment: The syntax is the same, but **how to I declare it in vb.net?**
`query = "select id, expiry date case when DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate) < 0 then 'Expired"`
How do I continue with the next `when`?

Comment: Research how to create multi-line strings in VB.NET.

Comment: From what I found, one way to do it is by using `_&` i.e. `"select serialNo, expiryDate case when DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate) < 0 then 'Expired'" _
                    & " when DateDiff(CURDATE(), expiryDate) < 7 then 'Expiring in 7 days'" `
But I'm still getting the error message.

Comment: I won't help with basic syntax errors, sorry. You need to take the necessary time to learn the basic syntax of a language before you try to solve more complex problems in it. So much material exists (including the official documentation) that teaches the basic syntax of VB.NET... Please take a step back and read up on the topic.

Comment: I have already done that, but I still can't find a solution. However, thank you for helping out.

Comment: The .NET IDE is so helpful in pointing out syntax and programming errors as you type, if you're still having a hard time then you still need to get more acquainted with the language. Keep at it, you will figure it out!

Comment: The error wasn't shown when I typed. It appeared from a caught exception when I debugged the application, telling me there was an error in the mysql syntax. But when I compared it with sqlfiddle link you shared, it's exactly the same.

Comment: Hm, I guess you need to get the SQL syntax straight first in mysql itself (use the [workbench](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/)). When the query works properly you can either make a view out of it or you can insert it into your application